# SELECT ODBC table and INSERT into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I have an ODBC connection to a database of which I need one table of data with 10 columns.

I need to insert this table into SQL Server database. I´ve tried to many ways to do it but still with any results.

```
OdbcConnection OCon = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=" + DbSource.SelectedItem.ToString());
SqlConnection SCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + SrvrDD.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";database=" + DdDestiny.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";User ID=id;Password=pass");
OCon.Open();
SCon.Open();

String QrySelect ="SELECT * FROM " + GridCon.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value;
OdbcCommand commandC = new OdbcCommand(QrySelect, OCon);
String QryInsert = "INSERT INTO " + DdDestiny.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".dbo." + GridCon.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value + " VALUES (@Sql)";
SqlCommand commandD = new SqlCommand(QryInsert, SCon);

OdbcDataReader Oreader = commandC.ExecuteReader();

commandD.Parameters.Add("@Sql",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5); 
while (Oreader.Read())
{
    string s = Oreader[0].ToString();
    commandD.Parameters["@Sql"].Value = s;
    commandD.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

Everything works fine but when commandB.ExecuteNonQuery(); get in, an error appears:

"The column name or the specified values do not correspond to the definition of the table."

Is the translation.

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what the issue is.. instead of writing your query that way.. I would suggest the following.
`1` create a stored procedure for your Insert command , user proper SqlParameters for both the Select and the Insert.. also use the `Debugger` `Oreader[0].ToString();` I would qualify the name of the field you are truly looking for for example `Oreader["FieldName"].ToString()` or `(string)Oreader["FieldName"]` also can you use `SqlConnection` vs Odbc..?